# How do I get the wearable preview?

Tags: android, wear-os

How can I get into the preview for implementing the new APIs for wearables?

Android Studio 0.6.1 does not offer an update to 0.8. Where to find the new Android Studio?

In order to use these new APIs I need to use a new play service library where do I find it?

Comment: Note: The Android Wear SDK has been released. It's no longer a preview. See rekire's answer below for how to get started with the full SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first you need the Android Studio **Beta** 0.8 from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). When done go the Android SDK Manager and install the required SDKs:

1. Update the Android SDK Tools and Platform-tools to versions 23 and 20 respectively.
2. Click Tools > Manage Add-on Sites > User Defined Sites.
3. Click New, enter https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-play-services-5.xml into the text field, and click OK.
4. Click Close. You should now see new emulator images that support this preview release of Google Play services and the Google Play services client libraries you need to start developing.

While the SDK manager is installing the stuff you need to work with go on to prepare your device:

For getting the lastest play services library you need to join this [comunity](https://groups.google.com/group/io14androidweardev/subscribe). Then you can download the [Google Play services 5.0 Preview](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.gms) and the [Android Wear Companion](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.wearable.app) which is needed to connect to a real wearable via bluetooth or the emulator. Next step is to install the beta version of the [Google Search](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) which is mandatory to use the emulator (if the Play Store says you already use the newest version wait for some minutes and try again).

See [more here](http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html).